# how to make a fixed banner so that content flows over it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

all searched every where and tried alot after that i'm to get help from here i have a banner and some divs below it but when i make banner position fixed the below it comes one the back of banner and banner shows over that div ....the div suppose to be right below after that fixed banner don't want to use 'top'property of css and if i use margin-top al content comes down leaving white space on the top

```
         <div class="header"></div>
         <div class="content">
         <div class="div1"></div>
         <div class="div2"></div>
         <div class="div3"></div>
         </div>

         .header{ width:100%; height:500px; background:#999; position:fixed;}
         .content{ width:100%; margin-top:300px;}
         .div1{ width:100%; height:400px; background:#09F;}
         .div2{ width:100%; height:400px; background:#FC3;}
         .div3{ width:100%; height:400px; background:#F30;}
```

please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fixed position needs to be told *where* to go.

Add `top:0;` and `left:0` to your `.header` class.

```
 .header {
     width:100%;
     height:500px;
     background:#999;
     position:fixed;
     top: 0;
     left:0;
 }
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E8kgr/

P.S. `500px` is a pretttttty big header. Just sayin'.

Comment: really appreciate your help bro ....a great help .........actually it wasn't a header its a banner